# Store reprojected coordinates in attribute table

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, attribute-table

I want to transform coordinates from gauss kruger to wgs84.
transforming ain't the problem as you can just set the layers reference to another but is there a way to print the new coordinates format into the attribute table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just "set" the CRS to another one, but only by `Save as...` from the context menue of the layer, where you can pick your new CRS and produce a new reprojected file,

or within the Processing Toolbox with **Reproject layer** which will give you a temporary layer with the new CRS.

To get the new coordinates written to the attribute table, either use the **Field Calculator** and **update** your coordinate columns (assuming you have points) with `$x` for the x-field and `$y` for the y-field.

Another way is to use the function **Export/Add geometry columns** from the Toolbox and then remove your old ones.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, adding the geometry column works fine, but when i reproject the layer or save as in another CRS, it seems as it does not really reproject the layer. if i set my layer from epsg:31467 to wgs84 (epsg4326) it stays where it was - but if i set the background also from gausskruger to wgs, the layer shows my points on the wrong place

Comment: I am quite sure that it does reproject the layer. It is more likely that you already mixed up some CRSs with the layers or you did not check on-the-fly reprojection in the project properties. Hard to tell from the distance without additional informations like example coordinates etc.

Comment: I have coordinates like this: 3468643,943; 5545451,282 --- 3468627,842 5545445,419; and want the latitude and longitude of those points. im quite sure that points are from gauss kruger z3 dhdn 31467 and want to know the exact same point as latitude and longitude in wgs84. now i added my coords as dhdn/ggk3 and picked save as ws84 - on the fly transformation is on - and all points shifted. same with reproject layer or when changeing the project crs or the layer crs. what am i missing? already tried to make a complete new project to prevent mixed up things but didnt help

Comment: How much is the shift? A screenshot would be cool. Strange indeed.